# What are the pros and cons of reusing variables in python?

Tags: python, variables

What are the pros and cons of reusing variables in python?
For example see this code:

```
pointer_1 = 0
pointer_2 = 0
# do insertion sort
pointer_1 = 0
pointer_2 = 1
# do selection sort
```

Will reusing pointer_1 and pointer_2 make my code's performance faster than not reusing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Variables are just references pointing to objects. Accessing them is a O(1) operation (a dictionary for globals, an array for locals), having more or fewer *doesn't matter*.

Stick to using the right variable names for the job. Focus on readability.